# Objective-c: Pass value from AppDelegate to UIViewController

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, appdelegate

I am launching an app from within another app and passing a value. I can get the value into the AppDelegate but I can't seem to access it from the ViewController. Here's the code I am using:

From App 1 (gets called on button touch):

```
NSString* str360URL = @"customer360://?customerNum=70044321";

    BOOL canOpenURL = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] canOpenURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str360URL]];

    if (canOpenURL) {
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:[NSURL URLWithString:str360URL]];
    }
```

From App 2 AppDelegate:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application openURL:(NSURL *)url sourceApplication:(NSString *)sourceApplication annotation:(id)annotation {

    if ([[url scheme] isEqualToString:@"customer360"]) {

        //check to see if we are passing in a customer number
        if ([[url query] rangeOfString:@"customerNum"].location != NSNotFound) {

            //get all the query string items (there should be only the customer num as of 6/01/14 but just in case they want to expand what is passed in
            NSArray* arrQueryComponents = [[url query] componentsSeparatedByString:@"&"];

            //loop
            for(NSString* strThisKVPair in arrQueryComponents) {

                //split the kv pairs into parts
                NSArray* arrKVPair = [strThisKVPair componentsSeparatedByString:@"="];
                //get the value from the kv pair
                self.strCustomerNum = [arrKVPair objectAtIndex:1];

            }

        }
...
```

There's more code in here for registration purposes. I can pop up a UIAlertView here and see the correct value on the property self.strCustomerNum, so I know appDelegate is storing it in its properties.

In ViewController I have this code:

```
//pass in the customer number
    self.strCustomerNum = ((AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate).strCustomerNum;
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"App View Controller" message:self.strCustomerNum delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:@"ok" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
    [alert show];
```

My alert doesn't show the customer number though. AppDelegate.h is being imported. Any thoughts on where I am going wrong here?

Comment: How/when is the code in your view controller being called? Maybe the alert view is being created before the code in `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:` has been executed

Comment: I've already resolved it - that was the issue - if it's running in the background the viewDidLoad method has already run. I'm accessing it from another method that runs off a notification and it works. But if you throw your comment in an answer I'll give you the credit.

Comment: Done. Glad you found a solution :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My best guess is that the code in your view controller is executed before the code in your app delegate, so the value of `strCustomerNum` is nil.

You can confirm this by setting breakpoints in your view controller and in your app delegate's `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`